# Where in Django code put code disconnecting signal and doing monkey-patching?

Tags: python, django, monkeypatching, django-signals

I'm working on custom authorization backend for Django 2.2. I don't want django to update `last_login` for user so I wanted to disconnect signal `user_logged_in` from triggering `update_last_login`.

I also have to do monkey patch in SimpleJWT library changing User to point OtherUserModel

Where is the best place to put this code? For now, I have added in `CoreConfig.ready` method and it works but is it a good place for this logic?

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'core'

    def ready(self):
        from django.contrib.auth import user_logged_in
        from django.contrib.auth.models import update_last_login
        user_logged_in.disconnect(update_last_login, dispatch_uid='update_last_login')

        import rest_framework_simplejwt.state
        rest_framework_simplejwt.state.User = OtherUserModel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes, but I think there is no clear right or wrong here, with regards to connecting signals, the Django docs state the following:

> Strictly speaking, signal handling and registration code can live
>   anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to avoid the
>   application’s root module and its models module to minimize
>   side-effects of importing code.
>
> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
>   submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are
>   connected in the ready() method of your application configuration
>   class. If you’re using the receiver() decorator, simply import the
>   signals submodule inside ready().

My opinion is that if the recommended way to connect signals is to do it in the `ready()` method of your `AppConfig`, disconnecting signals and related monkeypatching should also be done in this method.

What I always do is the following:

1. Is there any other way to solve this besides messing with the default signals/classes?
2. If not, perform this code in the AppConfig ready() method
3. Write some sort of unit tests or integration tests to ensure that my code does what I want it to do, even when updating dependencies etc.